# jQuery pass multiple variables through a method

Tags: jquery, variables, selector, global

Don't know if I'm missing something here. I'd like to run multiple global variables through the same method. See below

```
$('#pageMain .stuff, #pageMain .postFooter').each(function(){
    $(this).vertCenter();
});
```

But instead using the global variables:

```
$main, $titles, $footers
```

So something like...

```
$($main, $titles, $footers).each(). . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to call `each` on each jQuery object:

```
$footers.each(function(){ ... });
$main.each(function(){ ... });
$titles.each(function(){ ... });
```

Or, you could do the following:

```
var aggregated = $footers.add($main).add($titles);

aggregated.each(function() { ... });
```

Comment: but I'm trying to run vertCenter(); on each of them

Comment: technically couldn't I then say $footers.add($main).add($titles).each() ?

Comment: yes. though, if you're planning on using the aggregated version more than once i wouldn't do that ...

Comment: right, 'cause then it'd have to run sparkle() a billion times